# Pulling 50 RSS feeds and checking uniqueness of posts against database [Efficiency Advice]

Tags: sql, database, rss, performance

I want to pull several RSS feeds into a database as efficiently as possible.

My site will scrape 50 RSS feeds every 4 hours - I only want to add unique posts to the database. I am a bit stuck on how to check the post uniqueness. I am thinking I can compare the URL value and when the first post is not unique I can break out of the loop.

So my question is - is it better to pull all of the posts and check each feeds posts against an array until one duplicate comes up (and then break). Or is it better to search the database for the first post from each RSS feed - then only store that in an array and check the newly scraped posts against it.

I guess while I'm here I might as well ask if I should create a table for each separate feed. I am only storing 5 posts at a time so for now it is only one table and I just have a column to identify each feed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let the DBMS handle uniqueness: insert all the potential records using `where not exists` to screen out the existing ones.

Nothing in what you said suggests to me that you need a table for each feed.

No one can answer an efficiency question without knowing the DBMS in question.  As a rule of thumb, though, you're better off with bigger chunks of work and fewer transactions.  Storing 5 rows at a time may be a lot slower than, say, 5000 rows at a time.

Comment: I am using MySQL - I think this is what you mean by DBMS? Thank you for the reply!